# Add another column in result set instead of UNION

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4jclient

I have a set of nodes labeled as Person  and City. Node citiy has two properties Name and isInAustralia. A person can have relation 'hasHouse' relationship with the City node. A person can have multiple houses

I want to retrieve the data in such a way that it results in format:
Name of the person || CityInAustralia ||CityOutsideAustralia

suppose a person has a house in city A,D,E in the Australia and houses in city B,C outside the Australia.

The result I am getting is :

Adam----A----B

Adam----D-----B

Adam----E----B

Adam----A-----C

Adam----D----C

Adam----E-----C

I have tried the below written query:

```
Match(person:Person{Name:"Adam"})-[rel:hasHouseIn]->(city:City) 
where city.isInAustralia="true"
optional match (person:Person{Name:"Adam"})-[rel:hasHouseIn]->
(cityOutside:City) 
where city.isInAustralia="false"
return person.Name,City.Name as CityInAustralia ,cityOutside.Name as 
CityOutsideAustralia
```

I want results to be like:

Name           ----------     CityInAustralia ----------               CityOutsideAustralia

---

Adam------------A-----------------------------B

---

Adam------------D-------------------------C

---

Adam------------E-------------------------Blank

I want to get a result as what we get when we apply **left outer join** in sql sever where Name will be the column on which we will join.

Comment: You've not really said what's wrong - what results are you getting, why is it not valid?

Comment: But does left outer join even work that way in SQL? Wouldn't that also generate a cartesian product between all values of CityInAustralia and CityOutsideAustralia? There's nothing in the equivalent SQL statement that would pair off the results of the columns in the way you're describing.

Comment: Here i have **Adam** in common but lets's say instead of Name we have SSN (Socail security number)

Comment: Can you supply a SQL statement you would run to get that result? I'm with @InverseFalcon I can't think of any way you'd get the results you've listed - only the results as I have listed in the first query of my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I don't really know exactly what you're trying to do - the query won't work as it is as you have duplicate identifiers (`rel`) so you'd get nothing as a result. But also - if you have 'Adam' having 3 houses (A,D,E) in Australia, and 2 outside (B,C), you'll get:

```
A --> B
A --> C
D --> B
D --> C
E --> B
E --> C
```

Neo4j can't determine *which* of the `cityOutside` should be displayed with `cityInAustralia` as that would have to be a random guess, that seems like a post processing job. The query that will get you the results I've indicated above is:

```
MATCH (person:Person{Name:"Adam"})-[:hasHouseIn]->(city:City {IsInAustralia:true}) 
OPTIONAL MATCH (person)-[:hasHouseIn]->(cityOutside:City {IsInAustralia:false}) 
RETURN 
    person.Name, 
    city.Name AS CityInAustralia,
    cityOutside.Name AS CityOutsideAustralia
```

Personally, I would use `Collect` and get two arrays so you get:

```
CityInsideAustralia: [A,D,E], 
CityOutsideAustralia: [B,C]
```

So you only get one result per `Person`:

```
MATCH (person:Person{Name:"Adam"})-[:hasHouseIn]->(city:City {IsInAustralia:true}) 
OPTIONAL MATCH (person)-[:hasHouseIn]->(cityOutside:City {IsInAustralia:false}) 
RETURN 
    person.Name, 
    COLLECT(DISTINCT city.Name) AS CityInAustralia,
    COLLECT(DISTINCT cityOutside.Name) AS CityOutsideAustralia
```

NB. I'm using the below dataset:

```
CREATE 
    (p:Person {Name:'Adam'})-[:hasHouseIn]->(:City {IsInAustralia:true, Name:'A'}),
    (p)-[:hasHouseIn]->(:City {IsInAustralia:true, Name:'D'}),
    (p)-[:hasHouseIn]->(:City {IsInAustralia:true, Name:'E'}),
    (p)-[:hasHouseIn]->(:City {IsInAustralia:false, Name:'B'}),
    (p)-[:hasHouseIn]->(:City {IsInAustralia:false, Name:'C'})
```

Comment: Thanks @chris for prompt response. Yes i have tried using Collect 
But i want result to be in format where i have city in one row. I don't care about how many times Adam appears. I want my data to be dumped in excel and if i use Collect, when there will be thousands  of such person it won't look good in the cell and  will be tedious to read

Comment: By all means ignore the `COLLECT` bit - I added that with assumptions I'd made about your use-case and I should have got clarity :o - my fault!